# Updating mySQL entry with PHP not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to update a field in mysql database with this command:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE secretSanta SET giverAssigned = '$valueReciever[idsecretSanta]' WHERE idsecretSanta = '$valueGiver[idsecretSanta]';");
```

Is there something wrong with my code?
when printed these variable give the correct numbers

Updated : added code

```
include_once("config.php");
session_start();
        error_reporting( E_ALL );
        function passList($con){
        $giverLot = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT idsecretSanta FROM secretSanta  WHERE giftReq = 1 AND giverAssigned= -1 ORDER BY RAND()");
        $recieverLot = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT idsecretSanta, giverAssigned FROM secretSanta  WHERE giftReq = 1");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($giverLot) <=1){
            print("Not enough people are ready or available, no pairing possible. Could be result of a deadlock or everyone is already paired<br>");
        }

        $giver[] =NULL;
        $reciever[] = NULL;

        while($valueReciever = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recieverLot)){
            while($valueGiver= mysqli_fetch_assoc($giverLot)){
                if(($valueReciever[idsecretSanta] != $valueGiver[idsecretSanta]) && ($valueGiver[giverAssigned]<0)){
                    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE secretSanta SET giverAssigned = '{$valueReciever['idsecretSanta']}' WHERE idsecretSanta = '{$valueGiver['idsecretSanta']}';");
                    print($valueReciever[idsecretSanta] . "was given to " . $valueGiver[idsecretSanta] . "<br>");
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    print("The value is equal <br>");
                    print($valueReciever[idsecretSanta] . " Reciever was equal to Giver " . $valueGiver[idsecretSanta] . "<br>");
                }
            }
            $giverLot = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT idsecretSanta FROM secretSanta  WHERE giftReq = 1 AND giverAssigned = -1 ORDER BY RAND();");
        }
```

Comment: is there is any errors.

Comment: How do I see errors?

Comment: You can check about your errors setting your `error_reporting` `on` like as `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` also set `display_errors` `on`. Try updating your query like as `"UPDATE secretSanta SET giverAssigned = '{$valueReciever['idsecretSanta']}' WHERE idsecretSanta = '{$valueGiver['idsecretSanta']}'"` removed `;` and enclosed your variables within `{}`

Comment: If you are not getting any error then instead of passing `$valueReciever[idsecretSanta]` directly into the query assign them to a variable and then use it. Like `$reciever = $valueReciever[idsecretSanta]`

Comment: Just print your query and run it on the Phpmyadmin and check what error you get

Answer (score 0):

In your `query`, you need to use concatenation with array. Please try following query.

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE secretSanta SET giverAssigned = '".$valueReciever['idsecretSanta']."' WHERE idsecretSanta = '".$valueReciever['idsecretSanta']."'") or die(mysqli_error());
```

Even this query will return the error.

Comment: Strangely enough it didn't die.

Comment: The query is updating DB properly or not ?

Comment: It is not getting updated. The default value is -1 but it is not updating.

Comment: remove `; ` from the query

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE secretSanta SET giverAssigned = '$valueReciever[idsecretSanta]' WHERE idsecretSanta = '$valueGiver[idsecretSanta]';");
```

Remove the Semicolon and try

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE secretSanta SET giverAssigned = '$valueReciever[idsecretSanta]' WHERE idsecretSanta = '$valueGiver[idsecretSanta]'");
```

See if you are realy going inside the if condition using echo() and die()

```
if(($valueReciever[idsecretSanta] != $valueGiver[idsecretSanta]) && ($valueGiver[giverAssigned]<0)){
    echo "inside if condition";
    die();
                mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE secretSanta SET giverAssigned = '{$valueReciever['idsecretSanta']}' WHERE idsecretSanta = '{$valueGiver['idsecretSanta']}';");
                print($valueReciever[idsecretSanta] . "was given to " . $valueGiver[idsecretSanta] . "<br>");
                break;
}
```

Comment: Nothing seems to be working, and it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Just print your query and run it on the Phpmyadmin and check what error you get

Comment: check whether you are going inside the if condition

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put the quotes properly to access the array elements and the string concatenation also was not correct. Try this:

```
 mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE secretSanta SET giverAssigned = '{$valueReciever['idsecretSanta']}' WHERE idsecretSanta = '{$valueGiver['idsecretSanta']}';");
```

Comment: Guys, I am so sorry. It was actually because the if statement was never getting executed so the command to update wasn't running. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating the variables in curly braces and then testing the sql looks ok before executing. The field names in the array also required to be quoted as they are strings...

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $sql="UPDATE secretSanta SET giverAssigned = '{$valueReciever['idsecretSanta']}' 
          WHERE idsecretSanta = '{$valueGiver['idsecretSanta']}';"

    echo $sql;/* does it look ok?*/
    #mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
```